# How do clients "connect" to my RTPManager?

Tags: java, jmf

I have set up a Processor, an RTPManager, and have initialized it to a local IP calling

`RTPManager.initialize()`.

However, before I can continue, I need to add a target.
My problem is that I don't know the target up front.

With my custom viewer I can work around this by making a TCP connection first, therefore making the IP known to the server and doing a

```
RTPManager.addTarget()
```

I would really want it to be compatible with other viewers that can do RTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently with RTP, you need something like SIP or RTSP to initiate a session.